# Authenticating presto web interface

Tags: presto

Is there a way we can authenticate the web interface having cluster overview so not everyone can see queries running and only admin's of the system can access it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can authenticate is if you have LDAP configured. But that means any user who can authenticate to presto via LDAP can also authenticate to the Web UI. There is not authorization which means anyone can see anyone else's queries.